# Covariance calculation question

Tags: self-study, variance, covariance

$E(u^2)=\sigma^2$ And $\sigma^2$ is constant number.

How can I calculate $cov(u^2, \sigma^2)$

——-

Actual question is this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the formula for covariance.  All the information you need is there.

Comment: I calculate in that way $E(u^2\sigma^2)-E(u^2)*E(\sigma^2)=0$ is this true? @jbowman

Comment: And what is $E(u^2\sigma^2)$ when $\sigma^2$ is a constant?

Comment: Yes $sigma^2$ Is constant @jbowman

Comment: ... which doesn't answer my question.  Can you rewrite $E(u^2\sigma^2)$ making use of the fact that $\sigma^2$ is a constant?

Comment: In fact the actual question is this. And I add my answer way. The asked question is related to this posted question. @jbowman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75472/discussion-between-jbowman-and-studying1234).

Comment: E(u^2\sigma^2)=\sigm^2E(u^2)=\sigm^4$ @jbowman

Comment: Where did that $\sigma^4$ come from in your answer on the paper?

Comment: @jbowman since $sigma^2$ is constant var($\sigma^2$)=$\sigma^4$

Comment: We need to assume that not heterogenous @jbowman

Comment: Look at the answer below, and rethink your conclusion about the variance of $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Sorry I make mistake it should be zero. Well please say a comment about the solution for the actual question?  Thanks @jbowman

Comment: The question you are asking is not the question in the photograph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance between a random variable and a constant is zero because constants don't vary. In particular,
\begin{align}
Cov(u^2,\sigma^2) &= \mathbb{E}[u^2\sigma^2]-\mathbb{E}[u^2]\mathbb{E}[\sigma^2] \\
&=\sigma^2\mathbb{E}[u^2] - \mathbb{E}[u^2]\sigma^2 \\
&= 0
\end{align}
Note that because $\sigma^2$ is a constant, it can be pulled out of the expectation (and its expectation is just itself).

Comment: Okay I think the same. The actual question’s answer is going well? What do you think?  I assume that independent and not heterogenous and at the end, I got the answer $var(u^2)+\sigma^4$ What do you think?

Comment: By the same reasoning as above, $Var(\sigma^2) = 0$ since $\sigma^2$ is a constant

Comment: @studying1234 don't forget to accept answers you find helpful. ;)